# python argparse shell special chars

Tags: python, bash, shell, argparse

I have a script where one has to enter a password.
This works for most passwords, except for the "good" ones, where I get strange results.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test")

print(parser.parse_args())
```

and call it with

```
./test.py -t test$$test
```

will print

```
Namespace(test='test5365test')
```

The shell is treating the password as a special charakter.

My question is, if there is a way to disable that inside my code and not enforcing users to properly escape the character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the time your code gets the args, the shell has already processed them.  So you must protect them **on the shell command line** with single quotes or escaping.

For example, instead of

```
./test.py -t test$$test
```

you should use

```
./test.py -t 'test$$test'
```

Comment: single quotes are very acceptable, thanks, I also just discovered the beautiful standart python getpass module which is even better, not leaving passwords inside the bash history

Comment: Yep, better than `test\$\$test` to be sure!-)